# How to disable auto sign in on windows 10

Tags: user-accounts, windows-10, auto-login

I recently installed windows 10 and on the machine there are two accounts - let's call them u1 & u2. U1 is password protected and u2 is not. By default windows 10 auto logs in to the last user who logged off.

So, if u1 is last logged off, the next time the pc is started, it will stop at the welcome screen as it requires a password to log in u1. But if u2 is the last one, it will directly log in to the u2 desktop, as it does not require a password.

Me being u1, I find it very annoying to have to log out of u2 and log back into u1, every time I start my pc, if u2 was the last logged off user. Is there any way to avoid this, short of adding a password to u2 ??

Answer (score -1):

This is a quick and easy fix:

Log into your computer then right-click on the Start button and select "Run." Type "netplwiz" and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. This will bring up the User Account Window.

In this Admin tool, you can delete or add accounts which have or don't have a password requirement. Create a password through this method (and add the account if needed). Keep the box checked so that users must enter a username and password to use this computer. Don't forget to click "apply" at the bottom.

Restart your PC and they should both need the passwords you've created to sign in. The GUI is simple and easy to follow.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The OP doesn't want to add a password ...

Comment: It seems he may have to add a password. There is a mimic regediy key in windows 8.1 that's also in 10 but I can't confirm the effects. If they are fine; I'll happily type it out for him.

Comment: If you "can't confirm the effects" then it is a guess and not an answer.

Comment: That's why I didn't include the effects and just went with the safe option which apparently takes a password.

Comment: It's still not an answer. It's not what the OP wanted.

Comment: I don't think you want to admit we are 50/50 in the wrong here. I do agree I didn't answer it to his max extent but I never included unsafe details nor did I find any results that this is possible without a password. I'm sorry for this but I do defend myself. Last both and I hope you have a good day, sir.

Comment: The author does not need to give a password to the other user though, so the answer is incorrect, regardless of the fact it's not the best written answer quality wise

Comment: Ya... This would not help... I want to disable auto login without setting passwords...